# If i run multiple experiments at the same time, will the experiments not affect each other?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, abtest

I read here(https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/abtest-config) that I could run up to six experiments at the same time.

"To start your experiment, click Start Experiment. You can run up to 6 experiments per project at a time."

If i run multiple experiments at the same time, will the experiments not affect each other?

Answer (score 0):

The groups will overlap slightly if you have multiple experiments at the same time. So, for instance, if 5% of your users are in experiment A, and 5% of your users are in experiment B, then you should expect that 0.25% of your users will be in both experiments A and B.

In most cases, though, this shouldn't be a big deal because those users should be evenly distributed amongst your variants. But if there are situations where you think one variant of one experiment will disproportionately affect another variant of another experiment, then you might want to wait and run those two experiments serially.

For more information, you can also check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YGxrAB1MNEY).